# Numerically evaluating and plotting functions involving complete Elliptic integrals

Tags: plotting, numerics, special-functions

I have an equation like this

$$-K(y)-\frac{\pi  J}{2 \sqrt{\lambda }}+\frac{E(y)}{1-y}=0$$

```
1/(1 - y) EllipticE[y] - EllipticK[y] - (J π /(2 Sqrt[λ])) == 0
```

Where $E(y)$ and $K(y)$ are the Elliptic integrals in the Mathematica notation and $y$ is Real. I want to solve the equation numerically for $y$ for different values of the variables $(\lambda, J)$. That is $(\lambda, J)$ acts as a $(x,y)$ grid where $y$ gives the values along $z$ axis. Now I want to take these values of $y$ for different values of $(\lambda, J)$ and evaluate the function

$$\Delta= \frac{2 \sqrt{\lambda} }{\pi} \left(K(y)+\frac{\left(\sqrt{y}-1\right) E(y)}{1-y}\right)$$

```
(2 Sqrt[λ])/π ((Sqrt[y] - 1)/(1 - y) EllipticE[y] + 
  EllipticK[y])
```

and plot it in 3d along the $\Delta, \lambda, J$ axes. So the values on the 
 $(\lambda, J)$ plane remains the same, but instead of $y$, we want to plot $\Delta(y)$ at each $(\lambda, J)$ value.

Can someone help me write the code? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There were some syntax errors in your code, but here is a cleaned-up version:

Define the function (I used lam instead of Lambda):

```
fun[lam_, j_, y_] := 
 1/(1 - y) EllipticE[y] - EllipticK[y] - (j Pi/(2 Sqrt[lam]))
```

Note that FindRoot gives the root - for example:

```
FindRoot[fun[1, 1, y] == 0, {y, 0.1}]

(* y -> 0.642898 *)
```

Use Table to generate results for different values of lam, j and y:

```
data = Flatten[
  Table[{lam, j, y /. FindRoot[fun[lam, j, y] == 0, {y, 0.1}]}, {lam, 
    0.1, 0.5, 0.1}, {j, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1}], 1]
```

Define the Del function:

```
del[lam_, j_, 
  y_] := (2 Sqrt[lam])/
   Pi ((Sqrt[y] - 1)/(1 - y) EllipticE[y] + EllipticK[y])
```

Take y from the previously generated results and generate a new data set:

```
deldata = 
 Flatten[Table[{lam, j, del[lam, j, y]}, {lam, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1}, {j, 
    0.1, 0.5, 0.1}, {y, data[[All, 3]]}], 2]
```

Use ListPointPlot3D to plot

```
ListPointPlot3D[deldata]
```

Please note that the values of lam and j I have used are completely fictitious and may not be what you would want to use at all. But I do hope that the procedure is clear.

Comment: This works fine, thanks. One small problem, in the ListPlot the x,y axes are okay, but along the z axis the plot keeps showing values of y instead of values of \Del(y). Any idea why?

Comment: What I mean to say that ListPointPlot3D[deldata] and ListPlot3D[deldata] have different values on the z axis. One shows values of \Del(y) and other shows values of y. I'm bit confused there.

Comment: I think because of the values that I chose the roots are quite close to each other and therefore ListPlot3D doesn't really show this difference. Compare ListPointPlot3D[{{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1.01}, {1.01,
    0, 0}, {0, 1.01, 0}}] and ListPlot3D[{{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1.01}, {1.01, 0, 
   0}, {0, 1.01, 0}}]

Comment: By the way if your main question is answered could you please accept my answer ? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here another approach.

Equation 1 depends only on `J/Sqrt[lam]` , I call that Jlam.

```
eq1 = -((J \[Pi])/(2 Sqrt[lam])) + EllipticE[y]/(1 - y) - 
        EllipticK[y] == 0 /. J/Sqrt[lam] -> Jlam

eq2 = delta == (2 Sqrt[lam])/\[Pi] ((Sqrt[y] - 1)/(1 - y) EllipticE[
   y] + EllipticK[y])
```

Get an impression of solution with

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[eq1], {Jlam, -3, 3}, {y, -4, 4}, 
     WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

Show, how Jlam depends on y

```
sol1 = First@Solve[eq1, Jlam]

Plot[Jlam /. sol1, {y, -30, 1}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, 
   Epilog -> {Red, Point[{yMin, JlamMin}]}]
```

[image]

Previously found minimum

```
mi = Minimize[{Jlam /. sol1, -10 < y < 0}, y] // Quiet // FullSimplify

{JlamMin, yMin} = {mi[[1]], y /. mi[[2]]}
```

Get y as function of Jlam with FindRoot. Here I regard only the right wing of Jlam near zero.

```
 yfr[Jlam_?NumericQ] := 
    y /. First@
    FindRoot[-((Jlam \[Pi])/2) + EllipticE[y]/(1 - y) - EllipticK[y] ==
       0, {y, -.1, yMin, .99}]
```

Now calculate delta with y from yfr

```
delta[J_?NumericQ, lam_?NumericQ] := {y = yfr[J/Sqrt[lam]], (
    2 Sqrt[lam] (((-1 + Sqrt[y]) EllipticE[y])/(1 - y) + 
      EllipticK[y]))/\[Pi]}

Plot3D[Last@delta[J, lam], {J, 0, 3}, {lam, 0, 4}, 
   ImageSize -> 300] // Timing
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate method to produce @Akku's answer. Again, the dependence on $J$ and $\sqrt{\lambda}$ can be replaced by a dependence on a single parameter $x$:

```
eqn = 1/(1-y) EllipticE[y] - EllipticK[y] - (J \[Pi]/(2 Sqrt[λ])) == 0;
eqn = eqn /. {y->y[x], J -> x Sqrt[λ]};

eqn //TeXForm
```

> $-K(y(x))+\frac{E(y(x))}{1-y(x)}-\frac{\pi  x}{2}=0$

Next, we can turn this equation into an ODE:

```
ode = D[eqn, x];

ode //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{y'(x) (E(y(x))-K(y(x)))}{2 (1-y(x)) y(x)}-\frac{y'(x) (E(y(x))-(1-y(x)) K(y(x)))}{2 (1-y(x)) y(x)}+\frac{y'(x)
>    E(y(x))}{(1-y(x))^2}-\frac{\pi }{2}=0$

We can solve this ODE using [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve), but we will need an initial condition. Note that the equation evaluated at $y(x)=0$ gives:

```
eqn /. y[x]->0
```

> -(π x)/2 == 0

So, the initial condition is $y(0)=0$. Now, we are ready to use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue):

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{ode, y[0] == 0}, y, {x, -1, 1000}];
```

> NDSolveValue::ndsz: At x == -0.308082, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

We can use the above solution to create a function $yy(J, \lambda)$:

```
yy[J_, λ_] := sol[J/Sqrt[λ]]
```

Finally, we can insert this function into your $\Delta$ equation:

```
Δ = (2 Sqrt[λ])/π ((Sqrt[yy[J,λ]] - 1)/(1 - yy[J,λ]) EllipticE[yy[J,λ]] + EllipticK[yy[J,λ]]);
```

Visualization:

```
Plot3D[Δ, {J,0,3}, {λ,0,4}]
```

[image]